# Scanning pages of an out of print sefer for a friend

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, gezel-stealing

If someone is finding it hard to get hold of an out of print sefer, and it is prohibitively expensive to get it on a special order, would their friend, who owns the sefer, be allowed to scan the pages/sections of the sefer they need to aid in their learning, or is this stealing from the author/publisher? What's the difference between this and lending the sefer to the person? Does it make a difference if the friend lends the sefer and the person scans it himself?

Comment: Are you asking about halacha or secular copyright laws? You might find https://www.jlaw.com/Articles/copyright1.html and the next two pages of the article to be of interest

Comment: https://www.crcweb.org/ask_rav/copyright.php

Comment: Dina d'Malchuta Dina. FYI, unless you are talking about a recent, living author, classical content is most likely in what is considered the public domain. Specifically in regard to Chabad Chassidut, consider the consequence of the court case fought and won by the Rebbe in regard to Didan Netzach. To whom does the Rebbe's library belong? And in that context, take to heart the close of the 2nd Yehi Ratzon in Birchot HaShachar.

Comment: Most books contain a statement there should be no copying without written permission from the publisher. My experience is that when permission is requested from the publisher for the specified purpose, permission is granted. I advise this.

Comment: Those statements are aimed at mass copying with intent for resale. Also, they are only relevant to typesetting and layout, not public domain content.

Comment: @RabbiKaii what are you looking for?

Comment: @YaacovDeane halacha. Dina d'Malchuta if relevant.

Comment: @RabbiKaii In that case, see my first comment.

Comment: Given that Mi Yodeya does not deal in expertise in secular law and that DdM"D is implicated here, I recommend that you either specify in the question that the copying would or would not be considered a copyright violation in the relevant jurisdiction or explicitly ask for answers to address both cases. Note that the legal and practical status of copyright violations (e.g. tort, crime, frequently enforced, not) may also differ from jurisdiction to jurisdiction and from situation to situation.

Comment: @IsaacMoses can you temporarily close the question for me, and I will try to do some research into secular law on this first, and then I will ping you when I'd like you to reopen it? Or I could submit to the community

Comment: @RabbiKaii I've closed the question per your request.

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/93860/scanning-pages-for-a-friend for the consequential question on law.stackexchange